# WPF writing/confirming write to serial port

Tags: events, serial-port

I am writing a program which writes to a wireless device on the serial port. The firmware has a feature which will confirm the last message sent to the device was ok, so I'm trying to make use of that and update the settings readout on the GUI rather than ask the device for all of its settings every time I make a change. I think my code will explain it a little better:

```
// global variable 
bool queryStatusOK;

//event handler response from serial port
this.QueryStatusReponseEvent += QueryStatusResponse;

private void QueryStatusResponse(byte[] packet)
{
        if (packet[3] == 0) queryStatusOK = true;
        else queryStatusOK = false;
}

public void setParameter(string device)
{
    //send command to serial port to change a single device parameter
    Thread.Sleep(100); //sleep thread so 2 commands are not sent at once
    //send command to confirm previous command was received
    Thread.Sleep(100); //sleep thread to give time for confirmation to receive

    if (queryStatusOK)
        {
            //update GUI at this point
        }
}
```

The program is not consistent. It works sometimes, but not always. Even if I extend the thread sleep to a full second to give the boolean time to update, it still sometimes will not hit it. Can anyone suggest a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Mike

Comment: Nothing WPF specific. Removing the tag.

Comment: Using Thread.Sleep() is of course far too crude.  At least use a ManualResetEvent that you WaitOne(), call its Set() method in the QueryStatusResponse() method.  Clearly you'll need pass a large timeout value to WaitOne() and give up on doing it this way if WaitOne() returns *false*.  If you use the SerialPort.DataReceived event then stop doing that, you have no use for it if you want to wait on the response.  Just call its Read() method directly.  That also helps you avoid the kind of bugs your code *probably* is suffering from, like firing the event before the entire response is received.

Comment: I thought the Thread.Sleep() felt crude. I will give ManualResetEvent a try. Thanks!